# Code editor with SASS syntax highlight

Tags: ide, sass

Посоветуйте текстовый редактор с поддержкой синтаксиса SASS/Compass (Linux)
Пользуюсь Geany, но у него возникают косяки с сложенными правилами и сиимволами типа &: - подсветка как минимум скобок рассыпается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 через плагины поддерживает. Если приведете пример кода, вставлю в ST2 и покажу скрин =)